# How to retrieve list of 1000 plus repoistories in a GitHub org using GitHub API

Tags: shell, github, github-api

I am using the below script to generate a list of repositories in one of my GitHub Enterprise orgs and it works fine; however, by default it only fetches 100 repos at a time.

How can I modify it to generate the entire list? I have some 2000 repos in my GitHub org.

```
curl --silent --user "myusername:mypassword" "https://github.***.com/api/v3/orgs/myorg/repos?page=1&per_page=2000" | npx jq '.[].clone_url' | while read repo
do
    repo="${repo%\"}"
    repo="${repo#\"}"
    echo "$repo"
done > repolist.txt
```

I am unable to tweak the `page=*&per_page=*` here and no matter what number combinations I use, when I execute the above shell script, a file called `repolist.txt` is generated with the list of first 100 repos in the GitHub org.

Comment: Side note: use `jq -r` to suppress double quotes in output

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Benjamin. I added `-r` on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/traversing-with-pagination#basics-of-pagination)

> You can specify how many items to receive (up to a maximum of 100);

[You can go to `/orgs/{org}` and read `public_repos`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#get-an-organization)

With this value, you can make `total_pages=$(($public_repos / 100 + 1))` and iterate in `total_pages` incrementing your `page` prop.

Below is a small code, just add your credentials and Org Name:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

user=""
password=""
org=""
public_repos=$(curl -s -u "${user}:${password}" "https://api.github.com/orgs/${org}" | jq .public_repos)
per_page=100
total_pages=$(($public_repos / $per_page + 1))

for page in $(seq 1 $total_pages); do
  curl -s -u "${user}:${password}"\
    "https://api.github.com/orgs/${org}/repos?page=${page}&per_page=${per_page}" | \
    jq -r '.[].clone_url'
done
```

Comment: so what should i change in page=1&per_page=2000" to retrieve list of 2000 repos via single execution of my shell script

Comment: Thanks Wilton. For now i was able to redirect the output using >> repolist.txt and for 2000 repos had to run the script 20 times eact time with the page number as 1 then 2 then 3 and so on and per_page=100 since max per page allowed is 100.

Comment: I added a code to iterate over your total repositories without needs to rerun you program.

Comment: Thanks Wilton. But when i execute it it gives me below error
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 16
: line 8: / 100 + 1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ 100 + 1")

Comment: My bad looks like i messed up with the github url. its working now for me. But i can only retrieve public repos in that org. Can we do for all repos?

Comment: Of course, just get `total_private_repos` value and sum with `public_repos`. `total_pages=$((($public_repos + $total_private_repos) / $per_page + 1))`

Comment: another way of adding public and private repos - change the first `jq` command to: `jq '.total_private_repos + .public_repos'`